# Resizing a Quad with mouse coordinates in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, resize

I have a `Quad` object, I would like its four sides to move and expand (but do not shrink) with the movement of the mouse.

For example, if you move the mouse to the left, the `Quad` remains fixed where it is, but its left side moves to the left (the upper and lower sides stretch to the left), while the right side remains stationary. The same is true if I move the mouse to the other three directions. If the mouse moves inside the `Quad` nothing happens, but if it "pushes" against the edges, the Quad can be readjusted by increasing its size.

I thought it was easy, setting the coordinates of the mouse position with **x**, **y**, **xMax** and **yMax** of the `Quad RectTransform`, but I can not. I would have to dynamically change both the scale factor and the position factor x or y of the `Quad` seems to me quite complex.

Is not there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

RectTransform applies to UI elements, not quads rendered with a MeshRenderer. Default quad geometry is of dimensions 1 by 1, and its dimensions don't change unless you modify the Mesh itself, you can only change the scale.

As far as your questions goes, those are not very hard subjects, spend a couple of evenings messing around and you'll get there, complexity of the subject is actually quite low, and its a pretty good starting point to getting used to the 'unity way of doing things'